# Vue.js+Electron app has breakpoints unbound and doesn't stop on it in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron, electron-builder

I configured a Vue.js project with Electron using Electron Builder and I can1t debug it.
If I run my electron:serve script (which calls vue-cli-service electron:serve) in "Run and Debug" of VS it runs my app correctly, but sets the breakpoints of my main file (background.js), and any other, as **unbound**, as you can see in the image bellow:

[image]

I tried also to set launch.json with a "node.js electron main" config. But when I run debugger with this config it doesn't find the electron app at main.js, probably because main.js is a vue app.

```
    {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Electron Main",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "node"
    },
```

[image]

And if I exchange the main.js in this config to background.js it also doesn't find.

**I set breakpoint at background.js line 13.** And in main.js also.

I tried this config of launch.json also. Note that in cwd I have the path to my src folder, where I have the electron file, background.js, and stills it says that it did not find. I tried without the / after src also:
[image]
[image]

**[Here's my repository.](https://github.com/LucasPletsch/OwnTime)**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by unbound and the image doesn't clarify that for me. can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think that it might mean that the breakpoint is ignored by the Vue.js server, for a reason that I don't know. This post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384636/debugging-vue-in-vscode-and-chrome-unbound-breakpoint)  might help. Later I'll try to implement the changes suggested there

Comment: Try putting a debugger line at the very top of the file in whatever process you need to debug (I'm guessing `main` from your question text). Sometimes Electron likes to skip breakpoints, but it won't if you put a `debugger;` call at the top of the entry point (the first file you call that loads the rest)